# There has been an error processing your request Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm getting that message on the magento backedn and fronted

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1054980566331

that are the log errors:

```
[2017-01-31 14:56:06] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Warning: file_put_contents(/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---c40_CONFIG): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 663 in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/opt/bitnami/ap...', 663, Array)
#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(663): file_put_contents('/opt/bitnami/ap...', 'c40_GLOBAL_PRIM...', 10)
#2 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(179): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->_updateIdsTags(Array, Array, 'merge')
#3 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Core.php(390): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->save('a:3:{i:0;a:101:...', 'c40_GLOBAL_PRIM...', Array, NULL)
#4 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Core.php(74): Zend_Cache_Core->save('a:3:{i:0;a:101:...', 'c40_GLOBAL_PRIM...', Array, NULL, 8)
#5 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Adapter/Zend.php(47): Magento\Framework\Cache\Core->save('a:3:{i:0;a:101:...', 'GLOBAL|PRIMARY|...', Array, NULL)
#6 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(75): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Adapter\Zend->save('a:3:{i:0;a:101:...', 'global|primary|...', Array, NULL)
#7 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/TagScope.php(49): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->save('a:3:{i:0;a:101:...', 'global|primary|...', Array, NULL)
#8 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(75): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope->save('a:3:{i:0;a:101:...', 'global|primary|...', Array, NULL)
#9 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(75): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->save('a:3:{i:0;a:101:...', 'global|primary|...', Array, NULL)
#10 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Type/AccessProxy.php(85): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->save('a:3:{i:0;a:101:...', 'global|primary|...', Array, NULL)
#11 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(75): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\AccessProxy->save('a:3:{i:0;a:101:...', 'global|primary|...', Array, NULL)
#12 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/TagScope.php(49): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->save('a:3:{i:0;a:101:...', 'global|primary|...', Array, NULL)
#13 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php(305): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope->save('a:3:{i:0;a:101:...', 'global|primary|...')
#14 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php(248): Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->_loadScopedData()
#15 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(217): Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->getNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'setHttpResponse...')
#16 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/pub/errors/processor.php(206): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->setHttpResponseCode(503)
#17 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/pub/errors/report.php(14): Magento\Framework\Error\Processor->processReport()
#18 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(324): require('/opt/bitnami/ap...')
#19 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(160): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleGenericReport(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#20 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#21 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#22 {main} [] []
```

what can i do about it?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your cache directory has the wrong user permissions on it. This can happen if you run `index.php` as a user that is *not* the same as the web server's user, so the web server is then not able to read and/or write to the cache files.

To fix, you can try forcefully removing the cache files and regenerating them:

1. `sudo rm -rf var/cache var/full_page_cache`
2. `php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush`

If you prefer the non-nuclear option in a store with high traffic and don't want to remove all the cache files, you should `chown` the cache directory and its content to that of the web server user.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it thanks. The main problem now is that the luma theme works while the theme that i bought shows a blank page. the logs shows an error that i think that it is about that because it happened before the cache problem:

## 0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/opt/bitnami/ap...', 663, Array)